# Update Canvas Preserving Old Canvas Details

Tags: android, persistence, android-canvas

Hi I'm developing a game in android, for that I have draw 8*8 rectangles using canvas.drawRect() method, now what I need is when user touches on any of the rect, its color has to change. For this I have done as follows.

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(final MotionEvent event) {

        handleTouches(event.getX(), event.getY());

        return false;
    }

public void handleTouches(float x, float y) {
        xLocTouch = (int) x;
        yLocTouched = (int) y;
        outerLoop: for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
                if (GameView.tiles[i][j].rect.contains(xLocTouch, yLocTouched)) {
                    touched = true;
                    xTouched = i;
                    yTouched = j;
                    break outerLoop;
                }

            }
        }

    }

protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++) {
                canvas.drawRect(tiles[i][j].rect, paint);
                canvas.drawRect(tiles[i][j].rect, p);
                if(touched && i==xTouched && j == yTouched) {
                    Paint touchedColor = new Paint();
                    touchedColor.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                    canvas.drawRect(tiles[i][j].rect, touchedColor);
                }
            }
}
```

This code is works properly, but the problem is when I touch first time that rect's color changes, but for the second touch it erases old touches position. I need to keep all the touched rect as different color. Is there any way for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Boolean array that tracks the touch state of each rectangle would do the trick. I can't see the external code, but this could be an additional field in your GameView class, and updated appropriately in your handleTouches method.

A perhaps less efficient, less elegant solution would be to just not set the color of the rectangle in onDraw if it's already Color.BLUE (modify your if statement appropriately). You can get the color of the touched pixel using [this SE answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13550591/how-to-get-canvas-pixel), but be forewarned you have to first turn the canvas into a bitmap in order to sample the color (hence the inefficiency).